# Python blank readlines

Tags: python, file

userdb file:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

code:

```
with open("userdb","r",encoding='utf-8') as fl:
    user_count = len(fl.readlines())
    print(fl.readlines())
    print(user_count)
```

code output:

```
[]
3
```

there is no problem with length but it can't print the lines.Why and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines` can be called only once after opening file for single time without rresetting pointer to 0 by `fl.seek(0)`:

```
with open("userdb","r",encoding='utf-8') as fl:
    all_lines = fl.readlines()
    user_count = len(all_lines)
    print(all_lines)
    print(user_count)
```